# Как привязать умный фильтр к разделам каталога в bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

Суть вопроса:
1) Есть готовый каталог в интернет-магазине
2)Есть меню категорий
3) В каталоге есть разные платы и прочая электроника которая фильтруется в категориях по свойствам мощность квт, и есть остальные товары(не электроника), например шкаф.
Как сделать так чтобы при выборе в меню категорий электроники отображался умный фильтр по мощность квт, а при выборе остальных товаров он не отображался.

Comment: Оберни подключение компонента фильтра в if с условием "если находимся в разделе электроника..."

Comment: а можно как то без программирование реализовать?

Comment: А административной части в настройках инфоблока привязать свойство к разделу.